# Simple Argument Forwarding (what should my signature be?)

Tags: c++, arguments, weak-ptr

As an example, say I am writing a thin wrapper for a vector's push_back method.

```
class Foo
{
public:
   void myPushBack(Bar b);   // Line in question
private:
   std::vector<Bar> vec;
}

void Foo::MyPushBack(bar b)
{
   vec.push_back(bar);
}

main()
{
   Foo f();
   f.myPushBack();
}
```

My question is what is the correct signature for the function `myPushBack`?  Then my next question is what would be the correct signature for the function `myPushBack` if `vec` was of type `std::vector<weak_ptr<Bar>>`?

Comment: How about a universal reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you are using C++11, you should use the *perfect forwarding* idiom:

```
template<typename T> void Foo::MyPushBack(T &&b)
{
   vec.push_back(std::forward<T>(b));
}
```

Since it is a template, it does not matter the actual type of the vector. It will even take into account implicit conversions, such as `const char*` to `std::string`.